# Parse xml with javascript in html

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

hello i want to parse serverlist.xml with javascript to a html website. its working for me with country, hostname, name, map, numplayers and maxplayers, but when i want to parse the content of "players" with

```
table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("players")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

then i cant see anything more. i guess its because players tags have some more childnodes, but i dont know how to solve this problem. Thanks for any help.

serverlist.xml

```
<qstat>
  <server>
    <hostname>1.2.3.4:27966</hostname>
    <name>Server 1</name>    
    <gametype>Type 1</gametype>
    <map>q3dm3</map>
    <numplayers>3</numplayers>  
    <maxplayers>18</maxplayers>
    <numspectators>0</numspectators>
    <maxspectators>0</maxspectators>
    <ping>0</ping>
    <retries>0</retries>
    <players>
      <player>
        <name>E.Krenz^GDR</name>
        <score>6</score>
        <ping>0</ping>
        </player><player>
        <name>G.Schroeder^GER</name>
        <score>2</score>
        <ping>0</ping>
      </player>
      <player>
        <name>W.Ulbricht^GDR</name>
        <score>1</score>
        <ping>0</ping>
        </player></players>
  </server>
</qstat>
```

serverlist.html

```
<html>
<body>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
var x,xmlhttp,xmlDoc
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "../serverlist.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("server");
table='<tr><th bgcolor="#333333">Players</th><th bgcolor="#333333">Country</th><th bgcolor="#333333">Servername</th><th bgcolor="#333333">IP</th><th bgcolor="#333333">Map</th><th bgcolor="#333333">Players</th><th bgcolor="#333333">Connect</th></tr>';
for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
  table += "<tr><td>";
  table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("players")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += "</td><td>";
  table += '<iframe src="../serverlist/country/';
  table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("hostname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += '.php" height="25px" width="27px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>'
  table += "</td><td>";
  table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += "</td><td>";
  table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("hostname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += "</td><td>";
  table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("map")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += "</td><td>";
  table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("numplayers")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += "/";
  table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("maxplayers")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += '</td><td><a href="hlsw://';
  table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("hostname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += '/?Connect=1"><img src="../images/hlsw.jpg" width="13" height="13" border="0" />';
  table += '<img src="../images/pixel.png" width="10" height="10" border="0" /><a href="qtracker://';
  table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("hostname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += '?game=quake3&amp;action=connect"><img src="../images/qtracker.jpg" width="13" height="13" border="0" /></a>'
  table += '<img src="../images/pixel.png" width="10" height="10" border="0" /><a href="../serverlist/bat/';
  table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("hostname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += '.bat"><img src="../images/bat.png" width="13" height="13" border="0" /></a>'
  table += "</td></tr>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parsing XML to a DOM node-tree structure and traversing through it with JavaScript works somewhat differently in some browsers, depending on the commands you're using.  Solving this will eliminate some of the "unforeseeable issues" when working with DOM structures.  It could help parsing your XML to an object tree, (as with JSON) - after which you can traverse as you like without strange issues.  I can answer this by giving you a good "XML DOM to Object" parser function. If you want to try this, then comment back and I'll post an answer with the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please post your code. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments, below is a fully working example with a text-to-xml parser function as well as a concise data-type identifier.

The `simplify` function uses the above-mentioned functions to limit code duplication and complications, and converts the XML DOM structure into an object (or list of objects).

Each "node" has 3 aspects that represents an XML-node:

- `Kind` - the "nodeName" (tag-name)
- `Attr` - the attributes
- `Data` - the contents

You can change these "aspect names" as you see fit.

To test the code, simply copy & paste into a new HTML file, save & open it with your web browser (no web-server needed for this example).

The output of this example below will appear in the in the `web-console`; so, just open your web browser's "developer tools" and view the console log.

See the 3 lines of JavaScript in the last `<script>` element as instructions on how to use it.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <script>
            function typeOf(data)
            {
                var tpof = (({}).toString.call(data).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase());

                tpof = (((tpof == 'element') || (tpof == 'window') || (tpof == 'global')) ? 'object' : tpof);
                tpof = (((tpof == 'htmlcollection') || (tpof == 'namednodemap')) ? 'array' : tpof);

                return tpof;
            }



            function parsed(data)
            {
                var text, list;

                if (typeOf(data) == 'string')
                {
                    data = data.trim();
                    text = data.toLowerCase();
                    list = {null:null, true:true, false:false};

                    if (!isNaN(data))
                    { return (data * 1); }

                    if (list[data])
                    { return list[data]; }

                    if ((data.substr(0,1) == '<') && (data.substr(-1,1) == '>'))
                    {
                        var pars = new DOMParser();
                        var dxml = null;

                        try
                        { dxml = pars.parseFromString(data, "application/xml"); }
                        catch(err)
                        { console.log(err); }

                        if (dxml)
                        { return ([].slice.call(dxml.childNodes)); }
                    }

                }

                return data;
            }



            function simplify(dxml)
            {
                var resl, kind, indx=0;
                var list;

                if (typeOf(dxml) == 'array')
                {
                    resl = [];

                    for (var i in dxml)
                    {
                        if (!dxml.hasOwnProperty(i) || !dxml[i].nodeName)
                        { continue; }

                        kind = dxml[i].nodeName;

                        if ((kind == '#text') || (kind == '#comment'))
                        { continue; }

                        resl[indx] = simplify(dxml[i]);
                        indx++;
                    }

                    return resl;
                }


                resl = {Kind:dxml.nodeName.toLowerCase(), Attr:{}, Data:''};

                if (dxml.attributes && (dxml.attributes.length > 0))
                {
                    list = [].slice.call(dxml.attributes);

                    for (var i in list)
                    {
                        if (!list.hasOwnProperty(i) || !list[i].name || !list[i].value)
                        { continue; }

                        resl.Attr[list[i].name] = parsed(list[i].value);
                    }
                }

                if (dxml.childElementCount < 1)
                { resl.Data = (dxml.textContent || ''); }
                else
                { resl.Data = simplify([].slice.call(dxml.childNodes)); }

                return resl;
            }
        </script>


        <script id="xdom" type="text/xmldata">
            <qstat>
            <server>
                <hostname>1.2.3.4:27966</hostname>
                <name>Server 1</name>    
                <gametype>Type 1</gametype>
                <map>q3dm3</map>
                <numplayers>3</numplayers>  
                <maxplayers>18</maxplayers>
                <numspectators>0</numspectators>
                <maxspectators>0</maxspectators>
                <ping>0</ping>
                <retries>0</retries>
                <players>
                <player>
                    <name>E.Krenz^GDR</name>
                    <score>6</score>
                    <ping>0</ping>
                    </player><player>
                    <name>G.Schroeder^GER</name>
                    <score>2</score>
                    <ping>0</ping>
                </player>
                <player>
                    <name>W.Ulbricht^GDR</name>
                    <score>1</score>
                    <ping>0</ping>
                    </player></players>
            </server>
            </qstat>
        </script>


        <script>
            var text = document.getElementById('xdom').innerHTML;
            var xdom = parsed(text);
            var tree = simplify(xdom);

            console.log(tree);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

*If you find the code useful, don't forget to "up-vote", thanks ;)*

Comment: When i open the html file, i only see a blank white page.

Comment: check the console log, sorry, I'll edit the answer and say this in there also.

Comment: Answer is updated now and includes instructions to open your browser's web-console, where the results are displayed.